# Create azure VM images directly in Shared Image Gallery

Tags: image, azure, virtual-machine

I have created a virtual machine and created it's image in resource group. After this, I added this image to Azure shared image gallery.  It's taking around 55 minutes to be added. Is there any way to create the image directly in shared image gallery rather than first creating in rg and then adding it to image gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry that you cannot create the image directly in shared image gallery.

Currently, you can create shared image from portal, Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell. But, in each way, an existing managed image is need, which means that you have to create an image firstly outside of the shared image gallery.

For your concern about the long time consumption, there is a fair explanation: your image could be shared in different regions, so it is reasonable to take some time.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also searched but couldnt find anything. Might be in future this may come.